# Group by one field and order another field by rand in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table where there are two columns: parent_column and child_column

Here is what I want to achieve:
I would like to show count of parent column along with random child. I tried inner query but that does not make my thing work.

Here's my table:

```
Child          PARENT
1               55
2               55
3               55
```

Here is what I want:
On first refresh

```
parent count  child
55       3      3
```

On second refresh

```
parent count  child
55       3      2
```

and so on..

I tried this

```
SELECT t1.parent, count(*) count, t2. child
FROM t1
INNER JOIN (
SELECT parent, child
FROM t2
ORDER BY RAND()
) t2 on t2.parent = t1.parent
GROUP BY t1.parent
LIMIT 25
```

**EDIT:**
Here is a real world scenario:
Above table is of products, and each product has a parent. What I would like to achieve is that:
I would like to show 5 products on front-end.
Each product should have a unique parent. One more complexity is that on each page refresh, this product should be changed because the parent can have more than one products. 
Any help would be appreciated

Demo
On 1st refresh

```
Product Company
P1234   Samsung
P5555   LG
```

On 2nd refresh

```
Product Company
P2345   Samsung
P5123   LG
```

Thanks

Comment: What are you calling 'refresh' ??

Comment: @JorgeCampos on each execution of query. To get the random child value is what I mean.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Thanks for the answer. Can you please share one more thing? Are there any other precautions we can take regarding its performance?

Comment: Well the very first thing to consider is to have an index on parent column. Or one index for (parent, child). But you should test the execution plan for both cases and stick to the one that has the best performance.

Comment: Yeah, I have indexes for both columns. I will see what I can do more to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select t1.parent, count(*), 
       ( select child
           from test t2
          where t2.parent = t1.parent
           order by rand()
           limit 1 ) child
from test t1
group by t1.parent;
```

See it here on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4860c/3

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT t1.parent,
       (select count(*) from t2 where t2.parent = t1.parent) as count,
       t2. child
FROM t1
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 25;
```

I don't really see the purpose of the aggregation in the outer query.

Comment: Hey, thanks. It seems like this is what I want but I don't get how will this show my records grouped by parent because you did not mention group by with it. Also, the third column you are fetching is t2.child which we did not join. Any modifications or am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @RajaAmerKhan . . . Why do you want to group by the parent?  You seem to be choosing an arbitrary child from the table, and that does not necessarily involve aggregation.

Comment: actually the scenario is somewhat like, I would like to show 5 products on my front-end, each product should be random and should have a unique parent. Am I confusing you? :(

Comment: @RajaAmerKhan . . . If that is your question, ask another question and be much clearer about what you want to do.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will modify this question. I will add a bit more description to it.

Comment: @RajaAmerKhan . . . Modifying this question is very unfair to me.  I have answered the question that you asked.  If you modify it, then you will invalidate my answer and likely attract downvotes.

Comment: I am sorry, I just read it now. Do not worry. Our conversation is saved with stackoverflow and I request all the topic readers to not downvote you for your understanding of the questions. Sorry once again.